# Execute Macro when Database has finished processing / loading data

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle, vba, netezza

Is it possible to kick-off a macro when a database has finished processing and new data is available to query? Here are my thoughts on the matter so far:

**Possibility 1:**
A macro could be written to continuously query a database and check to see if the result set meets a certain set of criteria (e.g. Date range, result set not blank, etc.).

**Issue:** 
This would require a computer to always be on, always querying the same thing through Excel. This would also put too much stress on the servers.

**Possibility 2:**
Queries that are currently written can be reconfigured slightly to send emails to a newly created address. This email address (Outlook) will have a macro ready to trigger a batch file that runs macros requested.

**Issue:**
Reconfiguring the logic of the queries would be a large order, and I am not positive that this is even a comprehensive solution. I have seen promising things for [MS SQL Server](http://www.sherweb.com/blog/how-to-set-up-database-mail-for-sql-server-job-failures/) and for [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28419/u_mail.htm#i1001699) but not for Netezza just yet.

**Possibility 3:**
A bot can be made (in a language I currently don't know but am willing to learn :D) which will do the above, somehow avoiding a burdensome load on the server and the devotion of a laptop to always be on.

**Issue:** 
Likely fantasy. I'd like to be proven wrong.

NB: Microsoft SQL Server 2012

If these jobs are possible, please provide any advice / instruction possible.

Comment: what sql server are you using?

Comment: This question is too broad. Here's a broad answer: It's possible for SQL Server as a job. No need to run your computer on as they are executed on server side. I have a job that does all your 3 questions running on SQL SERVER 2012.

Comment: Do you have specific documentation I can follow for SQL Server? If possible, what about Oracle and / or Netezza?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are my recommended documentation for you to start looking into. I don't have any experience with Natezza but a quick search of the web shows various functions that you can utilize.

We use SQL Server 2012 for work and it's pretty easy to set up and manage.

**SQL Server / Oracle scheduling jobs**

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b25r0jDseOQ
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yttIsQvmrJc
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=91BSbNyL0lg
  -https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/schedadmin002.htm#ADMIN12037

**Sending Email**

- https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/10/send-query-results-sql-server-agent-job/
- https://www.brentozar.com/blitz/database-mail-configuration/
- https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/t_sysadm_set_up_sendmail.html
- http://www.folkstalk.com/2012/06/how-to-send-mail-from-shell-script.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I have for [SQL Server 2012](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZGDBB2uwNp8)

Here is what I have for [Oracle](https://www.experts-exchange.com/videos/471/Send-Email-From-Oracle-Database.html)

A solid answer for [Netezza](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.adm.doc/t_sysadm_set_up_sendmail.html) still remains out of reach for the moment, but this is the best lead I have so far.